# Is READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission ever required to read Uri from Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android

I was wondering, if I launch the following `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("application/zip");
startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCode.REQUEST_CHOOSE_BACKUP_FILE);
```

and try to read the returned Uri from intent in the following way.

```
Uri uri = data.getData();

// Figure out extension
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
final String extension = mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));

File temp = null;
try {
    temp = File.createTempFile(Utils.getJStockUUID(), "." + extension);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Delete temp file when program exits.
temp.deleteOnExit();

InputStream inputStream = null;
OutputStream outputStream = null;

try {
    inputStream = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(temp);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "", e);
} finally {
    close(outputStream);
    close(inputStream);
}
```

**Is `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission ever required?**

I tested a few round. To my surprise, I can perform success read without request for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

I just would like to confirm `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` isn't really required to read Uri from `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, in all type of situation.

Comment: That is true. Not required.

Comment: Thanks. I think @Tyler V provides an edge case using File Manager+

Comment: In theory it should not be required. In practice, bugs in `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` implementations might force you to hold that permission.

Comment: But what kind of uri do you get from FileManager? A content scheme or a file scheme? And how does it look like?

Comment: It looks like a normal linux file path pattern.

Comment: The Uri which requires permission looks like `/storage/emulated/0/Download/jstock_backup_12-jun-2018.zip`. The Uri which doesn't require permission looks like `/document/acc=1;doc=3566` or `/document/454`

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. In order to provide a better user experience, we plan to ask permission, only when the Uri requires permission. Do you know any good way, to perform such checking, to determine whether a Uri requires permission?

Comment: @CommonsWare We had tried `checkUriPermission`. But, it isn't reliable. Even we had granted permission, the Uri returned by `File Manager+`, still marked as ` PERMISSION_DENIED` by `checkUriPermission`.

Comment: "Do you know any good way, to perform such checking, to determine whether a Uri requires permission?" -- if it has a `file` scheme, you probably need that permission.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng If you come up with a scheme to reliably handle asking for permissions only when necessary please share it here, I'm definitely interested in that.

Comment: The URIs provided by the default Gallery apps of the Android 5 and Android 6 emulators still require the permission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had instances where a user had a third-party file manager installed ([File Manager+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alphainventor.filemanager)) and in those cases reading from the Uri returned by ACTION_GET_CONTENT would fail with a permission error if the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission was not first granted (only if they used the third-party app to select the file, if they used Google Drive or the normal system selection it worked fine without the permission).

I was able to replicate the behavior by installing File Manager+ on one of my emulators with the Play Store and trying it out.

Comment: Thank you for providing me some edge case. I tested just now in Android 8 using File Manager+. Yes. Permission is required in order to read the selected file properly.

Comment: For me everything works without the READ permission, even with the mentioned File Manager+ app, but some users reported the SecurityException crash, so I will try this solution. It is really weird though.

Comment: @MilošČernilovský for me it also works even with file manager+, have you checked your crashlytics if there is a crash related to this, or if this only happened in previous versions