# Export Android database to phone storage

Tags: android

A legacy Android app requires updating to pass Google's targetSdkVersion requirements.
One of the features was to export the SQlite DB to the phone's external (i.e. /sdcard/Downloads) storage so that it could be copied to a new device. This required a permission that's no longer allowed (MANAGE_INTERNAL_STORAGE IIRC) so I've had to change the code based on the suggestions at https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#java :

```
private static final int CREATE_FILE = 1;
publicVoid exportDb() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
  intent.setType("application/octet-stream");
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "myapp.db");

  Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("myapp.db"));
  intent.putExtra(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, uri);

  startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE);

}
```

This results in a file being created, but it's empty. What I am missing here?

EDIT: The problem is, I guess, that the lines of code I expected to open/read the sqlite database, don't. So, how would I pass that file to the ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT intent?

Comment: Remove the two lines before startActivityForResult() as they do nothing.

Comment: You start an activity for result but you are not waiting for a result. Implement onActivityResult() and use the obtained uri for the created file to write your file to.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the comments above. Would you be able to point me in the direction of an example, or more detailed explanation as to what is happening?

Comment: Sorry, this is so basic that a little googling will give you plenty examples.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. I wouldn't post here unless I'd spent time looking first.

Comment: `export the SQlite DB to the phone's internal storage ` I think you mean external storage.

Comment: Perhaps. I mean /sdcard/Downloads; in the case of my device I'd call that "internal" as it is not actually a removable sdcard.

Comment: Google calls that external. Have a look at getExternalStorageDirectory().

Comment: So you did not google for: ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT example.

Comment: No; I used DuckDuckGo. ;-)

Comment: On Android 13+ devices you can just copy your file to Downloads directory in the old classic way without needing any permission.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File written using ACTION\_CREATE\_DOCUMENT is empty on Google Drive but not local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51490194/file-written-using-action-create-document-is-empty-on-google-drive-but-not-local)

Comment: Initially I thought so, but I'm afraid not. My guess is that the lines of code I think should be reading the database file, aren't. So, a file is being written but there's no data in it to start with.