# Flutter image-picker explicitly ask permission

Tags: android, flutter

Imagepicker package says

> No configuration required - the plugin should work out of the box.
>
> It is no longer required to add
> android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" as an attribute to the
>  tag in AndroidManifest.xml, as image_picker has been
> updated to make use of scoped storage.

reading images from gallery.
so I think I need to ask some permission from the user as playstore also says this
New package is just working and not asking for any permission.
What permissions I need to explicitly ask
And I don't want to save it on any external directory I just want to upload image to firebase storage
Edit: image picker is not asking any permission from the user is this wrong

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Permission needed to read and write files in the android are.
These permission are required to be added to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**In your scenario, you don't need to do anything as this is already handled by the library**
https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Above mentioned library doesn't save the image in external storage.

> Note: Images and videos picked using the camera are saved to your
> application's local cache, and should therefore be expected to only be
> around temporarily. If you require your picked image to be stored
> permanently, it is your responsibility to move it to a more permanent
> location.

For more info you can refer to this link
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Accessing-the-Camera-and-Stored-Media#accessing-stored-media

**Update :**  How image picking is handled internally in `image_picker` for Android

**For Gallery** pick it opens in inbuild file picker intent using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`([about action get content](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_GET_CONTENT))

When opening file using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` - Because the user is involved in selecting the files or directories that your app can access, this mechanism doesn't require any system permissions. You can read more about [when permission is needed and when not in google docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files)

```
Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
  pickImageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
}
pickImageIntent.setType("image/*");

activity.startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_MULTI_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY);
```

and copies the result URI in temp file in cache directory and return the path

```
     String extension = getImageExtension(context, uri);
      inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
      file = File.createTempFile("image_picker", extension, context.getCacheDir());
      file.deleteOnExit();
      outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
      if (inputStream != null) {
        copy(inputStream, outputStream);
        success = true;
      }
```

**For Camera** library request the camera permission `android.permission.CAMERA` from the user and save the camera image in app cache directory.

```
private void handleCaptureImageResult(int resultCode) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
      fileUriResolver.getFullImagePath(
          pendingCameraMediaUri != null
              ? pendingCameraMediaUri
              : Uri.parse(cache.retrievePendingCameraMediaUriPath()),
          new OnPathReadyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPathReady(String path) {
              handleImageResult(path, true);
            }
          });
      return;
    }

    // User cancelled taking a picture.
    finishWithSuccess(null);
  }
```

This code is as per version `image_picker: ^0.8.4+4` code present on their github page - [image picker code](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/image_picker/image_picker)

Comment: but in my case image picker is not asking any permissions from the user is this policy threat for playstore

Comment: @Noobdeveloper , no it's not a threat to playstore policy , as in latest updates of image_picker opens the inbuild device gallery intent using 'Intent pickVideoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);' and created a temp file and path from the result content uri and returns us the image path.  Code for this is present on their github page - [imagePickerCode](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/image_picker/image_picker/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java)

Comment: So it means I don't have to anything in manifest

Comment: No , nothing to do in the manifest

Comment: App info section says no permission requested. And even in runtime app is not asking any permission to read gallery. This url says need read external storage permission https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage. And also when I am adding read permission it's saying denied and app is still working fine and not asking that request when needed. What to do only thing I am considered of playstore policy. Please suggest

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files - refer to this link , this explain why permission is not required and cases when you might require the permission

Comment: When opening file using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`  -  Because the user is involved in selecting the files or directories that your app can access, this mechanism doesn't require any system permissions.. 
You can also refer to this answer - [read permission ever required to read uri from intent action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826019/is-read-external-storage-permission-ever-required-to-read-uri-from-intent-action/50826220)

Comment: Hey now comes another question about data protection section https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/collect-share#photos-videos they are saying if you're collecting photos you should add or something like that and in flutter we are not doing that please help.

Comment: I didn't get your point , add what? Are you talking about permission or permission declaration to user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69960083/image-picker-permission-android-flutter check this post please

Answer (score 0):

You’ll have to add the above-mentioned permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml file. That is still required to access user storage.

Comment: After adding those two permissions. Still, my app is not asking permission in the runtimes. even I checked in my app permissions setting its saying denied and my app is running fine